# NLA Editor, only top track is working

Tags: animation

PLEASE can anybody tell me, why in the NLA Editor onloy the top track is activ, so the motion from bottom tracks is not shown?

THX

Comment: Hello, you don't give enough information, could you share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or at least show some screenshots?

Comment: I cant upload on "blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com". May I send you an Email?

Comment: My name is Andreas, my Email Adress cit0105@yahoo.de

Comment: in https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you need to enter the URL of this page then upload, it should work

Comment: I tried again, anyway, I cant find the solution to the problem.

Comment: In NLA Editor only top track is active...

Comment: This is my first visit in a forum, so I dont know the procedure..... :)

Comment: try on wetransfer

Answer (score 4):

This is a little dated, but for anybody having this issue in the future, I finally found out how to fix this issue..

I have been trying to use the NLA Editor as a generic timeline to construct my animation, so I have a huge amount of actions and an endless amount of tracks in the NLA Editor. I finally found that in order to get each track to play simultaneously (sp?) no matter it's track position, you need to

1) Hop over to the "Active Strip" options (Press N, then go to the "Active Strip" area

2) In the "Extra" dropdown menu, select "Nothing"

3) In the "Blend" dropdown menu, select "Combine"

That's it! Just make sure to do this with each action strip and everything will work good.... Note: You have to select the Action Strip itself, not the Track
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the old Blender (before 2.8).
For anyone who wants to know the answer to this:

Try turning off all star-symbols in the NLA editor,
and de-selecting any actions selected in the action editor by clicking the "x" button beside the action's name. (Tip: press the "F" button before clicking th e "x" to save the action.)

Note that action-stash tracks won't play, even though their action strips look just like any other action strips. You have to add actions to an NLA tracks (and not action stash tracks).

10:22 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weMes839wlc

And here's a great tutorial:
https://tab.gladly.io/search?q=500%2F4&src=ff65

The NLA editor can be so confusing... The guy in one of the videos even says this.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this! I was stuck in Blender 2.9 with only one Action strip playing at any time due to only one white star being select-able. I had no idea I can press that white star once more to unselect it so that all the tracks can play together!

Comment: @YusufIsmail You're welcome. So.... is NLA editor in blender 2.9 easier/easy to use than in Blender 2.7?... I've been wondering this, but kinda sounds like... not really? :/